# Move element to closest other element with class

Tags: jquery, move, closest

i have multiple articles on the page but i want to move the h2 heading into the (closest) flexslider div because i want the title over the image but i can't get it working.

HTML:

```
<article>
    <div class="flexslider"></div>
    <div class="post-content">
        <h2 class="entry-title">Title text</h2>
    </div>
</article>
```

What i want:

```
<article>
    <div class="flexslider">
        <h2 class="entry-title">Title text</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="post-content"></div>
</article>
```

The JS what not is working for me:

```
jQuery('article h2.entry-title').appendTo( jQuery('.flexslider') );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `append( function )`. For every `.flexslider`, find the `.entry-title` in the same `<article>` and append it:

```
$( '.flexslider' ).append( function() {
    return $( this ).closest( 'article' ).find( '.entry-title' );
} );
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z2kLtj3x/)

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```js
$("#appendTo").click(function() {
  $(".entry-title").appendTo($(".flexslider"));
});
$("#prependTo").click(function() {
  $(".entry-title").prependTo($(".flexslider"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flexslider" >sss</div>
    <div class="post-content" >
        <h2 class="entry-title">Title text</h2>
    </div>
    <button id="appendTo">appendTo main</button>
<button id="prependTo">prependTo main</button>
```

Comment: What happens when you have multiple `.flexslider` elements?